# touch multi UIViews

Tags: iphone

There are a series UIViews arranged very close.

[alt text http://www.mobilepanda.com/questiontouch.png](http://www.mobilepanda.com/questiontouch.png)

I hope when my finger touches some of them, my app can detect which UIView touched.
Maybe one or two or three.(because the displayed parts of each UIView are too thin).
I hope to get the middle x value of the touch, then spread the UIView where the middle x value locates and the UIViews near it.
[alt text http://www.mobilepanda.com/questiontouch1.png](http://www.mobilepanda.com/questiontouch1.png)

My way is put a transparent UIView over all these UIView to detect the touch event.
I am not sure if this is ok? or there is any better solution.(for example, make each UIView has the capability to detect the touch, mix and decide which UIView is touched.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do all that.  The OS will decide what the center point of the finger touch is and send an event with the touch x,y coordinates to the correct view.   If you make them UIButton's (a subclass of UIView) instead of UIView's the OS will do all the work for you.  All you have to do is attach callbacks to each button to the functions you want called for various events (like touchUpInside, touchDownInside, etc).